# How volume button is generated

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i've gotten this code from codepen and i was wondering if anybody could explain me how and where in the code the volume button is generated not the track but the megaphone symbol.

HTML

```
<h1>Youtube Volume Control</h1>
 <div class='bsp-volume-wrap'>
   <button id='bsp-volume'>
     <span class='fa fa-volume-up'></span>
   </button>
   <div class='bsp-volume-panel'>
          <div class='bsp-volume-slider'>
       <div class='bsp-volume-slider-track'>
         <div class='bsp-volume-slider-progress'>
           <div class='bsp-volume-slider-handle'></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700";
html, body {
font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333333;
text-align: center;
background: #1a1a1a;
}

h1 {
margin: 70px 0 50px;
font-size: 40px;
}

button {
   background: none;
   border: none;
   color: #cccccc;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 0 10px;
   height: 40px;
   outline: none;
   transition: color 0.2s;
   cursor: pointer;
   float: left;
   }
   button:hover {
   color: white;
   }

   .bsp-volume-wrap {
   padding: 0 10px 0 0;
   display: inline-block;
   }
  .bsp-volume-wrap #bsp-volume {
  float: left;
  }
.bsp-volume-wrap.bsp-volume-show button {
  color: white;
    }
.bsp-volume-wrap.bsp-volume-show .bsp-volume-panel {
  width: 73px;
}
.bsp-volume-wrap .bsp-volume-panel {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bsp-volume-wrap .bsp-volume-panel .bsp-volume-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.bsp-volume-wrap .bsp-volume-panel .bsp-volume-slider-track {
  height: 2px;
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background: gray;
}
.bsp-volume-wrap .bsp-volume-panel .bsp-volume-slider-progress {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.bsp-volume-wrap .bsp-volume-panel .bsp-volume-slider-handle {
  height: 12px;
  width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

Javascript

```
(function () {
var VolumeControl, control, getElementPercentage, bind = function (fn, me) {
        return function () {
            return fn.apply(me, arguments);
        };
    };
getElementPercentage = function (click, elm) {
    var rect;
    rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (click.pageX - rect.left) / rect.width * 100;
};
VolumeControl = function () {
    function VolumeControl() {
        this.volumeMute = bind(this.volumeMute, this);
        this.volumeStopHandler = bind(this.volumeStopHandler, this);
        this.volumeMoveHandler = bind(this.volumeMoveHandler, this);
        this.volumeDrag = bind(this.volumeDrag, this);
        this.volumeClick = bind(this.volumeClick, this);
        this.volumeHoverOut = bind(this.volumeHoverOut, this);
        this.volumeHoverIn = bind(this.volumeHoverIn, this);
        this.video = new Audio('http://garethweaver.com/codepen/media/bensound-jazzcomedy.mp3');
        this.video.volume = 0;
        this.video.play();
        this.elm = {
            volumeWrap: document.getElementsByClassName('bsp-volume-wrap')[0],
            volumeSlider: document.getElementsByClassName('bsp-volume-slider')[0],
            volumeProgress: document.getElementsByClassName('bsp-volume-slider-progress')[0]
        };
        this.elm.volumeWrap.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.volumeHoverIn);
        this.elm.volumeWrap.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.volumeHoverOut);
        this.elm.volumeSlider.addEventListener('click', this.volumeClick);
        this.elm.volumeSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', this.volumeDrag);
        document.getElementById('bsp-volume').addEventListener('click', this.volumeMute);
    }
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeHoverIn = function (e) {
        if (this.volumeHoverTimout) {
            clearTimeout(this.volumeHoverTimout);
        }
        return this.elm.volumeWrap.classList.add('bsp-volume-show');
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeHoverOut = function (e) {
        return this.volumeHoverTimout = setTimeout(function (_this) {
            return function () {
                return _this.elm.volumeWrap.classList.remove('bsp-volume-show');
            };
        }(this), 300);
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeClick = function (e) {
        var percent;
        percent = getElementPercentage(e, this.elm.volumeSlider);
        return this.volumeSet(percent);
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeSet = function (percent) {
        this.elm.volumeProgress.style.width = percent + '%';
        return this.lastVolume = this.video.volume = percent / 100;
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeDrag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.volumeMoveHandler);
        return document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.volumeStopHandler);
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeMoveHandler = function (e) {
        var percent;
        percent = getElementPercentage(e, this.elm.volumeSlider);
        if (percent < 0) {
            percent = 0;
        } else if (percent > 100) {
            percent = 100;
        }
        return this.volumeSet(percent);
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeStopHandler = function (e) {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.volumeMoveHandler);
        return document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.volumeStopHandler);
    };
    VolumeControl.prototype.volumeMute = function () {
        var vol;
        vol = this.video.volume > 0 ? 0 : this.lastVolume || 1;
        this.video.volume = vol;
        return this.elm.volumeProgress.style.width = vol * 100 + '%';
    };
    return VolumeControl;
}();
control = new VolumeControl();}.call(this));
```

For and easier way to read here is the link:  http://codepen.io/garethdweaver/pen/EjqNxO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Font Awesome:
https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Go there and search *(ctrl+F)* for "volume".

Font Awesome is loaded on the first line of the CSS file:

```
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

If you want to know more, visit the fa's home page: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

***edit:***
Besides CSS, the HTML file needs to use this simple line to show the megaphone:

```
<span class='fa fa-volume-up'></span>
```

Comment: thanks i'll look into it